# Deciding on music file size

Tags: c, audio, sdl

I am doing some programming with sdl. Before that I got a music file which says the property as below.

```
bit rate = 64kbps
audio sample rate = 8bit
channel = 1
audio sample rate = 8khz
audio format = pcm
```

The length is 26 seconds and what I would like to know how does it end up as 206Kb because if I take the 8KHz * 8bit * 26seconds does not make up to 206Kb? Then my music chunk alen gives me this size 3435760 ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the size is not KB (I.E. KiloBYTES, big B). This would line up closely with the sample rate and bit depth being used:

(8 Bits / Sample) * (8000 Samples / Second) * (26 Seconds) * (1 Byte / 8 Bits) = 208 KiloBytes

**Update:**
Replying to the comment, here is more information on translating the units posted in the question to the units in the formula.

Audio Sample Rate = 8khz. This is how many samples of audio there are for every second of audio. In this case 8000 samples per second, so this is the same as the (8000 Samples / Second) part of the formula.

Audio Bit Rate = 8bit: This is probably a typo, and you meant this value as the "bit depth" instead. The bit depth is just the size of a single sample of audio. This is equivalent to the (8 Bits / Sample ) part of the formula

Bit Rate 64 kbps : this means the audio file consumes 64000 bits for every second of audio. This is the same as (8 Bits / Sample) * (8000 Samples / Second) in the formula. So you can see bit rate is calculated from the bit depth * sample rate

Also, to clarify the (1 Byte / 8 Bits), this is just to convert the units from bits to bytes, so it is just dividing the result by 8.

Comment: What is the exact formula sample rate * samples * duration ? Why do we need the 1 byte times ?